# npm install on aws ec2 instance throw EACCES

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I've created a pre-configured node.js instance on AWS using ElasticBeanstalk, but the application does not run correctly. SO I connected to the instance and found out there is no node or angular cli, so I installed them manually. I then tried to run npm install in the application folder but failed, here is the output error.

```
[ec2-user@ip current]$ npm install
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /var/app/current/node_modules/tslib
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /var/app/current/node_modules/@ngx-loading-bar/core
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /var/app/current/node_modules/@angular/animations
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /var/app/current/node_modules/@angular/common
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /var/app/current/node_modules/@angular/compiler
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /var/app/current/node_modules/@angular/core
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /var/app/current/node_modules/@angular/forms
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /var/app/current/node_modules/@angular/http
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /var/app/current/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /var/app/current/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /var/app/current/node_modules/@angular/router
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /var/app/current/node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /var/app/current/node_modules/@ngx-loading-bar/http-client
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /var/app/current/node_modules/@ngx-loading-bar/router
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /var/app/current/node_modules/bootstrap
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /var/app/current/node_modules/ngx-mydatepicker
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /var/app/current/node_modules/ngx-toastr
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /var/app/current/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /var/app/current/node_modules/@ngx-loading-bar
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /var/app/current/node_modules/@angular
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /var/app/current/node_modules/@ng-bootstrap
npm WARN ng2-nouislider@1.7.7 requires a peer of nouislider@^9.0.0 || ^10.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm ERR! path /var/app/current/node_modules/tslib
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/var/app/current/node_modules/tslib'
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/var/app/current/node_modules/tslib'
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access \'/var/app/current/node_modules/tslib\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/var/app/current/node_modules/tslib' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ec2-user/.npm/_logs/2018-02-15T00_53_02_546Z-debug.log
```

I already installed node using version manager nvm, and tried also chown permission to nodejs:

```
drwxr-xr-x 16 nodejs nodejs   4096 Feb 15 00:25 node_modules
[ec2-user@ip current]$ cd node_modules/
[ec2-user@ip node_modules]$ ls -la
total 64
drwxr-xr-x 16 nodejs nodejs 4096 Feb 15 00:25 .
drwxr-xr-x  5 nodejs nodejs 4096 Feb 15 00:26 ..
drwxr-xr-x 11 nodejs nodejs 4096 Feb 15 00:25 @angular
drwxr-xr-x  5 nodejs nodejs 4096 Feb 15 00:25 bootstrap
drwxr-xr-x 13 nodejs nodejs 4096 Feb 15 00:25 core-js
drwxr-xr-x  6 nodejs nodejs 4096 Feb 15 00:25 font-awesome
drwxr-xr-x  4 nodejs nodejs 4096 Feb 15 00:25 ng2-nouislider
drwxr-xr-x  3 nodejs nodejs 4096 Feb 15 00:25 @ng-bootstrap
drwxr-xr-x  5 nodejs nodejs 4096 Feb 15 00:25 @ngx-loading-bar
drwxr-xr-x  4 nodejs nodejs 4096 Feb 15 00:25 ngx-mydatepicker
drwxr-xr-x  8 nodejs nodejs 4096 Feb 15 00:25 ngx-toastr
drwxr-xr-x  3 nodejs nodejs 4096 Feb 15 00:25 nouislider
drwxr-xr-x 14 nodejs nodejs 4096 Feb 15 00:25 rxjs
drwxr-xr-x  4 nodejs nodejs 4096 Feb 15 00:25 symbol-observable
drwxr-xr-x  3 nodejs nodejs 4096 Feb 15 00:25 tslib
drwxr-xr-x  4 nodejs nodejs 4096 Feb 15 00:25 zone.js
```

I appreciate if someone could help me resolve this problem,
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried running with sudo? `sudo npm install`

Comment: @EricUldall Instance does not have sudo command.

Comment: I think the problem might be your ownership. Is your user `ec2-user` a member of the `nodejs` group?

Comment: I thought nodejs is an user right @EricUldall?

Comment: @EricUldall add ec2-user into nodejs group does not fix the problem.

Comment: You not only need to add the user to the nodejs group, but you need to fix your permission also. Notice, `drwxr-xr-x`: you only have read and execute setup for the group (`r-x`). You can can try `chmod -r 0775` on that folder and see if it resolves the issue.

Answer (score 12):

It's a LINUX permissions issue, your ec2-user doesn't have write permissions in that directory.

I faced the same issue recently and my workaround was the following:

*Note that I'm not an expert in UNIX neither AWS so maybe there is a better/cleaner/easier solution to this issue.*

### Having node and npm installed globally:

Log as root user using: `sudo su` and run `npm install`

### Having node and npm only installed in **ec2-user**:

- Log as root user using: `sudo su`
- Create a group of users: `sudo groupadd mygroup`
- Now that the group exists, add users to it:

```
sudo usermod -a -G mygroup root
sudo usermod -a -G mygroup uc2-user
```

- Now all that's left is to set the permissions on the directory:

```
sudo chgrp -R mygroup /path/to/the/directory
sudo chmod -R 777 /path/to/the/directory
```

- Now you can exit as root user: `exit` and run `npm install` as **ec2-user**

Comment: `sudo usermod -a -G mygroup uc2-user` needs to be changed to `sudo usermod -a -G mygroup ec2-user`

Comment: This is the best terse answer in order to do this the right way per user, thanks